# Battery drain issues with Android GPS recording service

Tags: android, gps, firebase, battery

My service records the location of the user and sends it to Firebase every X minutes.  I have tried changing X from 1 minute to 5 minutes, however the change in battery drain was less than 1 percent.  In both cases it works out at about 5% used by the app every 3 hours.

I am trying to understand how increasing the GPS interval by 500% had little or no impact on the battery life.  Not only is the GPS firing 1/5 of the time, but there is also 1/5 of the data being sent/received to Firebase.

When the watching location is turned off, battery drain is 0.

Any ideas as to what is causing the drain?  Also, what kind of battery drain should I be looking at for getting a GPS location every 5 mins and sending about 50 bytes of data with it?

Comment: Cleaning up comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate concern is how you connect to Firebase. Keep in mind that Firebase will keep an open connection to the server from the moment you call `new Firebase(...)`. If you only want to periodically send/listen for data, you'll needlessly be draining the battery.

You can programmatically manage the connection state with [`goOffline()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#goOffline--)/[`goOnline()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#goOnline--).

If you're only sending updates, you can use the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) to write the updates. This won't keep an open connection, or at least leaves it up to Android to determine when to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the major cause was the mobile data.  As soon as I made it require wifi to use firebase the battery drain dropped from 20% a day to 2%.